# Integer Programming unequal constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, integer-programming

I am trying to model the following constraint in a MIP:

```
x_1 +x_2 + ... +x_n != d
```

The idea is to introduce a variable z that is 1, if x_1 +x_2 + ... +x_n = d and to add the constraint

```
z <= 0.
```

But I cannot figure out how to model the constraint

```
(x_1 +x_2 + ... +x_n = d) ==> z=1
```

in an integer program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume all `x_i` are integers. Let `L` and `U` be constants such that

```
L <= x_1+x_2 + ... +x_n <= U
```

and `y` a binary variable. These constraints express what you are looking for:

```
x_1+x_2 + ... +x_n >= d+1 + (L-d-1)y

x_1+x_2 + ... +x_n <= d-1 + (U-d+1)(1-y)
```

If `y=0` then the first constraint `x_1 +x_2 + ... +x_n >= d+1` must hold and the second constraint `x_1+x_2 + ... +x_n <= U` is satisfied by the definition of `U`.

If `y=1` then then the second constraint `x_1 +x_2 + ... +x_n <= d-1` must hold and the first constraint `x_1+x_2 + ... +x_n >= L` is satisfied by the definition of `L`.

(Please check for typos.)

---

This is the **infamous big M method** in integer programming. It can lead to poor relaxations and it can also lead to ill-conditioned problems.

---

For further tricks, google "integer programming tricks". In particular, see [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_integerprogrammingtricks.pdf) for this big M method trick.